# Can [DllImport()] handle static c libraries

Tags: c#, .net

Can I import static C library with .lib extension.

I have header files with:  extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

I can generate necessary code with P/Invoke assistant from the header source code, but the question remains,

Can [DllImport()] handle compiled C/C++ lib files ?

Comment: No, you will have to compile it as a DLL with the functions exposed.

Comment: Does that mean that i should create native wrapper project with the same interface and then compile my own dll and then import that in a C# application ?

Comment: Either that, or maybe create a managed interface directly by using C++/CLI (I would go for the latter, less work)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DllImport` works by referencing the entry as defined in the module's (.DLL) exports table.  .LIB files are not modules nor do they have an exports table as per .DLLs.

From MSDN:

> *The DllImportAttribute attribute provides the information needed to call a function exported from an unmanaged DLL. As a minimum requirement, you must supply the name of the DLL containing the entry point.* - [Tell me more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute(v=vs.90).aspx)

Your question of:

> *Can [DllImport()] handle static c libraries*?

No.

But you can always link the .LIB into a .DLL (assuming you know c/c++) and p-invoke the resulting DLL  but that is an indirect solution and does not imply a *"Yes"* to your question.

Comment: well, you have answered the question, but it's worthwhile to mention that there is a way to import and use c++ libraries in .net

Comment: Agreed, but via an indirect approach

Comment: is it enough to include same header file, create wrapper for each function from the lib and then compile it ?

Comment: Perhaps, but I would have thought the easiest thing to do was list each function in your .DEF file under the `EXPORTS` section.  Easier than cloning the code